# Answers to array in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I'm trying to plot a graph with while and if condition.

```
vf = vi + a*t
vt = (2*m*g/(C*p*A))**(1/2)

while t<1000:
    vf = vi + a * t
    t+=1
    if vf<vt:
        print(t)
    else:
        pass
```

So vf is velocity and vt is terminal velocity.
I want vf to increase as long as its smaller than vt which I've done so as you can see from the code.

The problem I have is the X components(in this case, t).
It shows like this:

```
0
1
2
3
...
```

and so on
Is there any commands that changes to array such that it will be like
[0,1,2,3,...]

Thank you

Comment: you could append to a list and then use `join` after the while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a list.

```
_list = []
_list.append(1)
_list.append(2)
_list.append(t)
```

Print simply outputs a variable to the next line. If you replace your print with append as shown above it will add it to an array. I modified your code and displayed below.

```
vf = vi + a*t  
vt = (2*m*g/(C*p*A))**(1/2)  

t_list = []  
while t<1000:  
    vf = vi + a * t  
    t+=1  
    if vf<vt:  
        t_list.append(t)  
    else:  
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `end` to print items in one line

change `print(t)` to `print(t, end=" ")`

Answer (score 0):

I think you asking for the below code:

```
vf = vi + a*t
vt = (2*m*g/(C*p*A))**(1/2)
arr = []
while t<1000:
    vf = vi + a * t
    t+=1
    if vf<vt:
        arr.append(t)
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alter the way you are calling the print() function in order to define what the ***end*** will be. take a look at this example:

```
>>> def print_array(array):
...     print("[ ",end="")
...     for i in array:
...         print(i, end=", ")
...     print("]")
... 
>>> print_array(range(0,5))
[ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ]
>>>
```